# How to access pasteboard info in iOS keyboard extension project

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have set full access for the keyboard extension and add RequestsOpenAccess in the info.plist file. but access UIPasteboard.general.string  return nil.
But I see some other input keyboard apps can full access the pasteboard like Baidu keyboard.
so how can I do it? as I know , the simulator can read the pasteboard info, but the real phone failed.

Answer (score 0):

After some test and I find the issue,in the viewdidload function when you read the pasteboard most probably you will get nil but in the viewWillAppear function you can read pasteboard info correctly. So that's weird.